# PHP MySQL Query of view returns 0 results when there should be a result

Tags: php, mysqli, mariadb

I have a site that is running PHP 5.6. The database for the site was recently upgraded from MySQL 5.1 to MariaDB 10.0 (MySQL 5.5 Compatible) and now a query on my site won't work (and it was working without error when connecting to the MySQL 5.1 database.

For this demo, I have a database table called "content" with fields "id" (integer), and "page_title" (var_char). In that table are two rows - one with an ID of 1 and page_title of "Test 1", and the second row has ID of 2 and page_title set to "Test 2".

I then created a view of this table using the following query inside of phpMyAdmin:

```
select `content`.`id` AS `id`,`content`.`page_title` AS `page_title` from `content`
```

I can see the view and both rows from the content table in the view in phpMyAdmin.

On my PHP page, I have a object oriented style query. That code is:

```
<?php
try {
require_once 'Connections/dbconn.php';
$sql = "SELECT id, page_title FROM v_content WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $db->stmt_init();
if (!$stmt->prepare($sql)) {
    $error = $stmt->error;
} else {
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $page_title);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->fetch();
}
} catch (Exception $e) {
$error = $e->getMessage();
}?>
```

This query is returning the following: Attempt to read a row while there is no result set associated with the statement

If I change the table from the VIEW "v_content" to just the table "content", I get a result returned. Additionally, if I use the same query (querying the VIEW v_content), and connect to a MySQL 5.1 database, I get results returned. I know there is nothing wrong with the query itself, as I have copied and pasted the query into phpMyAdmin and have had results returned, and the exact same code was used on a MySQL 5.1 database and that returned results. I have checked the error logs and there are no errors being shown.

Anyone have any idea what could be causing me to get 0 results returned from the view?

Comment: The "Attempt to read a row..." error should not occur with a SELECT statement. It usually implies you tried to `fetch()` on an `UPDATE` or `INSERT` statement (or you already closed the result set). Your use of `store_result()` looks suspect to me here. Since you are calling `$stmt->fetch()` and have used `bind_result()`, I don't believe you need `store_result()`, especially since you are not even storing its returned result resource into a variable. Remove that line and see if your situation changes.

Comment: If I remove  - $stmt->store_result(); - nothing changes. It still returns 0 results.

Comment: But does it still report the same error? That seems unlikely with the posted code.

Comment: No errors are being reported now. In fact, if I put that line of code back in, and try it again, no errors show then either. I added some dummy text to the page just to make sure it wasn't being cached, and the dummy text appeared and no errors were shown. There is still no results returned from the query however.

Comment: I went to PHP's website, and copied their demo code from this page: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php - I updated their code for Object Oriented Style with my table fields/table, and still no results return. No error message are produced, but no results are produced either.

Comment: Provide `SHOW CREATE VIEW`.

Comment: The SHOW CREATE VIEW code was posted in the original post, but I will edit the most to make it stand out more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like after all, there was no issue on my end with the actual coding of the site. The hosting company gave me the following explanation:

It appears that the issue with prepared statements working incorrectly with views was related to the table_definition_cache size on the new maria database servers. This is a global setting, and essentially, if the number of tables put into cache exceeds this value, it starts flushing older entries out of the cache.  It appears that if a statement is prepared, but the entries leave the table_definition_cache before the prepared statement is executed, it's considered "invalid" and needs to be re-prepared. Since this is a global value, the accessing of others tables can reset its counter. As a result, we increased the value of table_definition_cache to a much higher value on all of the database servers, which has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to switch the places of execute and bind.

```
...
} else {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $page_title);
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->fetch();
}
...
```

Comment: This was tried, but unfortunately the results are the same.